# Jmeter Benashell Post processor error -- How to do please suggest

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Not able to generate file using beanshell post processor.. 
trying to calculate time difference as well 
   ******* Beanshell Post processor code *****

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.jmerer.services.FileServer;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.Writer;
log.info("Chetan Mali")
log.info(vars.getObject("SQL_Result_CM").get(0)+"");
String pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date startDate=null;
Date endDate=null;
for(int i=0; i<vars.getObject("SQL_Result_CM").size(); i++ ){
    if(vars.getObject("SQL_Result_CM").get(i).get("process_name").equals("Initializing Data for The Target"))
    {
        //Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(vars.getObject("SQL_RESULT").get(i).get("start_time"));
        startDate=vars.getObject("SQL_Result_CM").get(i).get("start_time");
    }
    else if(vars.getObject("SQL_Result_CM").get(i).get("process_name").equals("Processing Done"))
    {
        //Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(vars.getObject("SQL_RESULT").get(i).get("start_time"));
        endDate=vars.getObject("SQL_Result_CM").get(i).get("start_time");
    }
}
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\chetan.mali\\Desktop\\Chetan Jmeter\\Output\\CM_timediff_output.csv");
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file, true);
// true, will append the file if already exist
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write(vars.get("DataID_CM")+","+(endDate.getTime()-startDate.getTime())+"\n");
out.close();
fstream.close();
log.info("######################################################################");
log.info(""+(endDate.getTime()-startDate.getTime()));

******* Beanshell Post processor code ***** 


******* Logs ***** 

2019-08-02 11:46:39,765 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2019-08-02 11:46:39,765 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2019-08-02 11:46:39,765 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2019-08-02 11:46:39,765 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2019-08-02 11:46:39,765 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2019-08-02 11:46:39,765 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2019-08-02 11:46:39,765 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2019-08-02 11:46:39,781 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2019-08-02 11:46:39,781 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2019-08-02 11:46:39,781 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2019-08-02 11:46:39,781 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: C:/Users/chetan.mali/Desktop/Chetan Jmeter/Output/CM_output.csv
2019-08-02 11:46:40,326 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.text.DateFormat; import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; import java.sql. . . . '' Encountered "log" at line 11, column 1.

2019-08-02 11:46:40,326 WARN o.a.j.e.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.text.DateFormat; import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; import java.sql. . . . '' Encountered "log" at line 11, column 1.

2019-08-02 11:46:40,342 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.text.DateFormat; import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; import java.sql. . . . '' Encountered "log" at line 11, column 1.

2019-08-02 11:46:40,342 WARN o.a.j.e.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.text.DateFormat; import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; import java.sql. . . . '' Encountered "log" at line 11, column 1.

2019-08-02 11:46:40,342 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2019-08-02 11:46:40,342 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2019-08-02 11:46:40,342 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2019-08-02 11:46:40,342 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Close: C:/Users/chetan.mali/Desktop/Chetan Jmeter/Output/CM_output.csv
2019-08-02 11:46:40,342 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)


******* Logs *****
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your sampler code to [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) which execute Java with `log` variable in context

> some variables are set up. Note that these are JSR223 variables - i.e. they can be used directly in the script.
>
> `log` - the Logger

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a semicolon to your `log.info("Chetan Mali")` line like:

```
log.info("Chetan Mali"); //<--- this semicolon is uber important
```

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

[Groovy performance is much better comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/), moreover it provides a lot of [enhancements](https://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html), for instance [Date](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html) class has  and [format()](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.util.TimeZone)) function so you don't need the SimpleDateFormat, etc.